# Automake: Include extra files in default sources

Tags: automake

I'm writing some simple tests for my library, and I'm trying to keep my Makefile.am file as tidy as I can, so I'm trying to rely on the [default _SOURCES](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/automake/manual/html_node/Default-_005fSOURCES.html) functionality. This is my current Makefile.am:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = $(MYLIB_CFLAGS) -I..
AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT = .vala
AM_LDFLAGS = $(MYLIB_LIBS)
VALAFLAGS = -D GLIB_2_32 --vapidir=../ --pkg mylib_internal --pkg libsoup-2.4 --pkg json-glib-1.0 --pkg gee-1.0

TESTS = autocomplete
check_PROGRAMS = autocomplete

autocomplete_LDADD = ../mylib.la
autocomplete_SOURCES = autocomplete.vala common.vala

CLEANFILES = *.c
```

If I leave out the `autocomplete_SOURCES` variable, autocomplete.vala is automatically used, and that's great (as per the default _SOURCES functionality), but I *need* to include common.vala as well. In fact, every test program I am going to write will want to have this common.vala in their source file list. Is there a way for me to not having to specify the `*_SOURCES` for every single test program I write?

Bonus: They will all want to have mylib.la in their `*_LDADD` as well, so again, is there a way for me to accomplish this globally, instead of having to have it specified for every test program?

**EDIT:** I figured out that you can just use `LDADD` without the prefix to get it to apply to every compiled program. That helps a bit... now to figure out the `*_SOURCES`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this.

You can introduce a variable that you use everywhere, if you want:

```
general_stuff = whatever.vala
x_SOURCES = $(general_stuff) ...
y_SOURCES = $(general_stuff) ...
```